# Android/MySQL: How to a radio button is checked based from value at MySQL

Tags: java, android, mysql, xml, android-layout

Currently I have trouble based on my question above. I Have two radio button in one radio group. The first radio button is "Approved" and the second radio button is "Rejected". Example, if I clicked the radio button "Approved", the value from that checked radio button will save to MySQL. Then, if I want to display back the value of Radio button, how will the radio button "Approved" is display as Checked? (don't want to display back as TextView).

Below is my code on how I get all the value from edit text to text view.

This code is retrieve from database and display as textView.

```
    etName = findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etBadgeID = findViewById(R.id.etBadgeID);
    etDepartment = findViewById(R.id.etDepartment);
    etFactory = findViewById(R.id.etFactory);
    etPosition = findViewById(R.id.etPosition);
    etReviewer = findViewById(R.id.etReviewer);
    etTitle = findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
    etMonth = findViewById(R.id.etMonth);
    etYear = findViewById(R.id.etYear);
    etSuggestwill = findViewById(R.id.etSuggestwill);
    etPresent = findViewById(R.id.etPresent);
    etDetails = findViewById(R.id.etDetails);
    etBenefit = findViewById(R.id.etBenefit);
    imgAttach = findViewById(R.id.imgAttach);
    rgStatus = findViewById(R.id.rgStatus);
    etComment = findViewById(R.id.etComment);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    User user = (User) intent.getSerializableExtra("user");

    etName.setText(user.getName());
    etBadgeID.setText(user.getBadgeid());
    etDepartment.setText(user.getDepartment());
    etFactory.setText(user.getFactory());
    etPosition.setText(user.getPosition());
    etReviewer.setText(user.getReviewer());
    etTitle.setText(user.getTitle());
    etMonth.setText(user.getMonth());
    etYear.setText(user.getYear());
    etSuggestwill.setText(user.getSuggestionwill());
    etPresent.setText(user.getPresent());
    etDetails.setText(user.getDetails());
    etBenefit.setText(user.getBenefit());
    imgAttach.setImageBitmap(base64ToBitmap(user.getPhoto()));
    etComment.setText(user.getComment());
```

This is how I store value radio button at the database (at Submit Button)

```
int selectedId = rgStatus.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
radioButton = findViewById(selectedId);
final String status = radioButton.getText().toString();
update(status);
```

Method for update(status)

```
private void update(final String status){
    class updateClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

        private ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = 
ProgressDialog.show(NeedApproval.this,"Updating.....",null,true,true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            //creating request handler object
            RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

            //creating request parameters
            HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("status",params[0]);
            //returing the response
            return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(URLs.URL_UPDATE, data);
        }
    }
    updateClass ulc = new updateClass();
    ulc.execute(status);
}
```

Comment: You can get the database value and then check the value using `if else` condition. `if value Approved` you can set approved radio button. If not you can set the `Rejected` radio button. Before that, you need to check the value when loading the activity or as your need.

Comment: thanks for your contribution. can give the code? @Hasitha M Jayawardana

Comment: How are you connect to the MySQL? Can you post the `update(status);` method?

Comment: @Hasitha M Jayawardana done updated

Comment: Do you get database data from a `PHP` file?

Comment: yes. can you solve it?

Comment: Post your database structure.